# Intercept WebView Request in Android

Tags: java, android

I like to add Authorization in request header in Android. I have tried below code but didn't work. In the back .NET MVC header comes null. I have been googling the issue for a day now. Please help or let me what is mistake I am doing

```
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
       webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
       webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

       webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:4200", getCustomHeaders());

       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
           @Override
           public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
               request.getRequestHeaders().put("ClientId", "ANDROID");
               request.getRequestHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer Vd7NPdgQYU54DgX769T55M");
               return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
           }
       });

   private Map<String, String> getCustomHeaders()
   {
       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
       headers.put("ClientId", "ANDROID");
       headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.");
       return headers;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 'WebViewClient' class and set it.
Int WebViewClient, you can override function as follow.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("ClientId", "ANDROID");
    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.");
    view.loadUrl(url, headers );

    return new WebResourceResponse("", "", null);
}
```

Comment: ````class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("ClientId", "ANDROID");
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.");
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString(), headers );
            return new WebResourceResponse("", "", null);
        }
    } Like this ??